# DJANGO Form Clean

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
   date = models.DateField()
```

Form:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_date(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        status = cd.get('status')
        date = cd.get('date')

        if not date and status == 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError((mark_safe('<p class="text-danger">When status is .... You must add date </p>')))
        return date
```

My clean function not work. How is wrong ? Can you help me ?

Comment: add details please, your data, and what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are [cleaning fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), then you should override the `clean` method instead of `clean_date`.

Since `status` is a foreign key, it will never be equal to `1`. Perhaps you want to check the primary key, in which case you should use `status.pk`.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
    status = cleaned_data.get('status')
    date = cleaned_data.get('date')
    if not date and status.pk == 1:
        raise forms.ValidationError((mark_safe('<p class="text-danger">When status is .... You must add date </p>')))

    return cleaned_data
```